# Laravel/Angularjs: Insert into pivot table with less queries

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I succeeded at creating a simple "add topic" form to test laravel's pivot operations. It consists of a title, body and tag checkboxes. My models are `Post`, `Tag` and the pivot `PostTag`.

After reading the Laravel documentation on updating pivot tables, it seems to me that I'm making way too many queries to simply create a new topic and update the pivot's table. Also, the way I pass on the checkbox values (tags) seems kind of sloppy to me.

Here is my Angular controller:

```
app.controller('NewPostController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.selection = [];
    $http.get('/new_post').success(function(tags) {
    $scope.tags = tags;
});

$scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(tag) {
    var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(tag);

    // is currently selected
    if (idx > -1) {
        $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
    }

    // is newly selected
    else {
        $scope.selection.push(tag);
    }
    };

    $scope.addPost = function() {
        $scope.post.selection = $scope.selection;
        $http.post('new_post', $scope.post).success(function() {        
        });
    }
```

... and my Laravel controller:

```
class PostController extends BaseController {
    public function add() {
        if($post = Post::insertGetId(array('title' => Input::json('title'), 
                                           'body' => Input::json('body')))) {
            $tags = [];
            foreach(Input::json('selection') as $tag) {
                array_push($tags, $tag['id']);
            }
            $new_post = Post::find($post);
            $new_post->tags()->sync($tags);
        }
    }
}
```

With this I'm actually making 5 queries to achieve the final result. However, I followed Laravel's documentation on this. Should I use a normal query instead?

Thanks!!